# Get list of sites that uses specific plugin or theme

Tags: plugins, multisite, themes

One of most time saving in mutisite is to know where some plugin or theme is used.

So i start searching and did not found any solution for this.

What i need is help to get list of sites that uses specific plugin or theme.

i thought the best will be to add link near each plugin in network plugin page, and when we click on "get sites list" we will get the list of sites that use this plugin.

To add link to the plugin list we can use filter `network_admin_plugin_action_links` and for the themes we can use `theme_action_links`.

[image]

The question is how to get list of all sites that use plugin/theme based on click?

Comment: [Plugin Activation Status](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-activation-status/) plugin may help you.

Answer (score 2):

[Multisite Enhancements](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-enhancements) is plugin that apparently does a lot of stuff, including showing which blogs use which plugins.  I haven't had a chance to try it myself, but I've had my eye on it.

If you wanted your own code, vs. using a plugin, I suppose you could poke around inside the plugin to see how it works for them.